# Why does FFmpeg encode by default?

Tags: ffmpeg, open-source, video-encoding, video-editing, design-decisions

By default the following unpresuming FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" "output.mkv"
```

...will lossily encode a file unless it has the `-c copy` flag added, which will then pass the video through without any encoding. I remember not realising this as a beginner to FFmpeg years ago and being surprised when I found out, and ever since then it's something I've wondered about but not got around to asking.

The main justification for this behaviour that comes to mind for me is that encoding is a much more common operation, and it might be annoying to have to pass an extra `-encode` flag for most uses.

Was this ever one of the reasons cited for this design decision? Has the issue ever even been discussed in the FFmpeg mailing lists, or has it remained unquestioned since being written during the days of Fabrice Bellard?

Comment: Why does ffmpeg encode by default? Hmm... The process of encoding converts information. `ffmpeg` is a converter. So the default action corresponds its essence.

Comment: ffmpeg supports hundreds of containers. FFmpeg can't assume that a container will accept the input codec, so it transcodes.